# Conditional expectation of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $$X_1, X_2, \ldots$$ are i.i.d. random variables with an exponential distribution with mean $\mu$. Suppose $N$ is independent of $(X_i)_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ and $$\mathbb{P}(N=k) = p(1-p)^k$$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ Let $S_{N} = \sum_{k=1}^{N}X_k$ and $S_N = 0$ whenever $N=0$. Calculate the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[N \mid S_{N}\right]$.

Any hint would be great, I wouldn't have any problems with calculating $\mathbb{E}\left[S_{N} \mid N \right]$ or if a random vector $(S_N, N)$ had density. I don't have any smart idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: do you want $E[N\mid S_N]$ or $E[S_N\mid N]$ ?

Comment: As my question says, I want $\mathbb{E} \left[ N \mid S_N\right]$, calculating $\mathbb{E} \left[ S_N \mid N \right]$ is easy.

Comment: While I have not worked out any details, does the following naive approach not work? Start by figuring out the conditional probability $\mathbb P_{S_N \mid N}$, use Bayes theorem to get $\mathbb P_{N \mid S_N}$, then just sum up $\sum_k k \mathbb P[ N=k \mid S_n]$ to get your final result.

Comment: $P(S_N=x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. $S_N$ has the Erlang distribution with parameters $N, λ$.

Comment: @air, if you were so kind to expand your idea, I'd be really grateful. I used the Bayes theorem only in the discrete version, never have I heard of it in the continuous case.

Comment: @tosi3k : You can use the formula: $$P[N=n|S=s] = \frac{f_{S|N=n}(s|N=n) P[N=n]}{f_S(s)}$$ To understand this, you can imagine multiplying by "$ds$" on top and bottom: $$\frac{\left(f_{S|N=n}(s|N=n) ds\right)P[N=n]}{f_S(s)ds} \approx \frac{P[S \in [s, s+ds]|N=n]Pr[N=n]}{P[S\in[s,s+ds]]}$$

Comment: $$E(N\mid S_N)=\mathbf 1_{S_N\ne0}+\mu^{-1}(1-p)S_N$$